# Journey with Salesforce Event Data - Change Contact Key of injected lead

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I configured a Journey in marketing cloud with a salesforce event data related to the task object.
Everytime a task is created, the lead will entry in the journey.
However I need to inject the contact with a different contact key, that is not the Salesforce Lead Id, but it must be an External ID.
Have you ever handled this requirement?

In the contact builder -> Data Designer, I tried to change the link between Customer Data and Task (Entry event Data Extension) changing the link from Contact Key <-> Task:WhoId to Contact Key <-> Task:External_Id__c , but any lead is injected into the journey.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible, to my knowledge. Any injections into a Journey, that is based on a salesforce entry event, will be based on Salesforce record Id - this is true regardless of leads, contacts or person accounts.

If the External_ID__c is equal to your subscriber key in the connected cloud environment, please be aware that you are effectively cutting yourself off from all the standard features, including showing email tracking etc. inside sales/service cloud.

If you need external id for other purposes, you can simply include the external id in your event data, so that it'll be populated with a value that can the be leveraged in ampscript, other activities etc, - but the contact key will still be the salesforce record id.